# How do I replace a single word repeated multiple times with a word from list?

Tags: python, json, regex, lambda, python-itertools

What I have tried so far seems to

```
node_id = {'method': 'date','method': 'nodeid', 'id': serial_number}
    date = {'method': 'date'}
    frequency = {'method': 'freq', 'id':serial_number}
    bandwidth = {'method': 'bw' , 'id':serial_number}
```

Comment: Hi, the sample code you provided did not clarify how the data came to be, apart from the definition of `level_1_methods_lst`. You need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
For example, how does the dictionary came into existance, who is generating them.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! My first time posting in Stack Overflow. I have updated.

Comment: you probably shouldn't post your api endpoint with the ip address together publicly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample code using the first three values of `level_1_methods`:

```
level_1_methods  = [
  {"result": ["51485"], "id": "51485", "jsonrpc": "2.0"},
  {"result": ["1515106787"], "jsonrpc": "2.0"},
  {"result": ["2240"], "id": "51485", "jsonrpc": "2.0"}
]

level_1_methods_lst = ['node_id', 'date', 'frequency']

for i in range(len(level_1_methods)):
  key = level_1_methods_lst[i]
  value = level_1_methods[i]['result']

  level_1_methods[i][key] = value
  level_1_methods[i].pop('result')

  print(level_1_methods[i])


>>> {'id': '51485', 'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'node_id': ['51485']}
>>> {'date': ['1515106787'], 'jsonrpc': '2.0'}
>>> {'id': '51485', 'frequency': ['2240'], 'jsonrpc': '2.0'}
```

You will need to change `level_1_methods` from a tuple to a list. Additionally, the outputted dictionary is ordered alphabetically which shouldn't make a difference if you ever need to extract the information. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do it with a simple `for`, like this:

```
for item in level_1_methods_lst:
    data_str = data_str.replace("result", item, 1)
```

Hope it helps